# Mule 3.3.1 CE integration with Twitter

Tags: mule, esb, twitter4j, mule-studio

I get the following stack trace when I run the order discounter example application from Mule Studio 1.3.2 x64 (Mule 3.3.1 CE runtime) on JDK 1.6.0_21 (32-bit) Windows 7 x64 :

```
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,507 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting connector: connector.https.mule.default
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,517 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,527 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,527 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,527 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.https.mule.default.dispatcher.11950696'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-06-25 10:29:13,527 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.https.mule.default.dispatcher.11950696'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2013-06-25 10:29:14,047 [[orderdiscounter].order_management.async1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: String
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : Order #: 1 Date: 2013.06.25 10:29:13 CDT Order total: 12300.0
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Could not authenticate with OAuth
 (twitter4j.TwitterException)
  org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector:687 (null)
2. Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.twitter.processors.UpdateStatusMessageProcessor:164 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
Could not authenticate with OAuth
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00000000 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00000000
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[00000000-00000000], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
    at org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector.updateStatus(TwitterConnector.java:687)
    at org.mule.twitter.processors.UpdateStatusMessageProcessor$1.process(UpdateStatusMessageProcessor.java:153)
    at org.mule.twitter.adapters.TwitterConnectorProcessAdapter$1.execute(TwitterConnectorProcessAdapter.java:36)
    at org.mule.twitter.processors.UpdateStatusMessageProcessor.process(UpdateStatusMessageProcessor.java:139)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:186)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:179)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:178)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can you help me troubleshoot this ? I have setup the twitter account for read-write access and have provided the values for `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` as per the [mulesoft documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configure+Twitter+for+API+Access).

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by moving to Mule 3.4 CE x64. However, what went wrong with 3.3.1 CE is unknown.